# Pegar valor de uma celula em jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-3

[image: Como faço para pegar o valor de uma celula quando clico no botao **ALTERAR ENDERECO?** de uma tabela em jquery?]

Este botao tem um evento ONCLICK que chama uma função.
Teoricamente, ele ja esta em uma linha, precisaria apenas do VALOR de uma celula.

obs: **Enderecos** é o ID da tbody e o **TESTE** é o ID da CELULA.
Funcao atual:

```
function teste(){
            var id = $(this).parent().find('td').attr('id');
            alert(**enderecos**[1].**teste**);
            }
```

Funcao para recuperar os dados na tela:

```
 function atualiza(){
                $.ajax({    
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'get_enderecos.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        for(var i=0; data.length>i;i++){
                            $('#enderecos').append('<tr><td id="teste">'+data[i].sequencia+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td>'+data[i].cep+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td>'+data[i].endereco+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td>'+data[i].bairro+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td>'+data[i].cidade+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td>'+data[i].estado+'</td>'+
                                                    '<td class="actions col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" align="center">'+
                                                        '<button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="teste()" type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>'+
                                                     '</td></tr>');

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
```

Comment: `TESTE` é o `id` da celula que quer buscar ? Mas relembro que não pode ter id's repetidos numa página

Comment: Qual valor vc está enviando à função `teste()`? Se não enviar nada, é impossível fazer o que vc quer.

Comment: Posta a parte do código onde você imprime esses dados na tela. (deve ser um while ou um json, seja o que for)

Comment: na funcao teste, se eu der um alert(enderecos.cep) ele me retorna um indefined.

Comment: Sim, teste é o ID da celula que eu quero buscar

Comment: `<tr><td id="teste">` -> **isto cria-lhe várias linhas com o mesmo `id` que está incorreto a nivel de html**  [Veja aqui na documentação da W3C como os ids tem de ser únicos](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Começo por indicar que o `id` que está a colocar no primeiro `<td>` da linha não está correto pois vai lhe gerar varias linhas com `ids` repetidos. No html o atributo `id` tem de ser único na página.

[Citando a documentação da W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute):

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs

Traduzindo:

> O valor tem de ser único de entre todos os IDs

Para corrigir este problema pode transforma-lo numa classe, trocando o `append` por:

```
$('#enderecos').append('<tr><td class="teste">'+data[i].sequencia+'</td>'+ ...
//--------------------------------^ agora class
```

Com esta troca já o html está certo e para ir buscar este `<td>` no `click` pode fazer assim:

```
$("body").on( "click", ".actions .btn.btn-danger", function() {
    let htmlTeste = $(this).closest("tr").find(".teste").html();
});
```

Repare que eu utilizei a função [`on` de jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para usar delegação e garantir que o `click` funciona mesmo em elementos que sejam futuramente adicionados à pagina.

Com a função [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) vai até ao `<tr>` acima mais próximo e com o [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) desce de novo até ao `<td>` com a classe `teste`.

Comment: Vou testar, e venho postar os resultados! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @leonardobarussi Sem problema, se tiver alguma questão não hesite